# Calling methods from a Javascript Object

Tags: javascript

If I have

```
var function_holder = { 

        someFunction: function () { } 
};
```

How do I call `someFunction`.

Also is there a way to write someFunction outside of function_holder?

Thanks

Comment: function_holder.someFunction(); 

I don't understand your second question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`function_holder` is an object, `someFunction` is a method.

Call `function_holder.someFunction();` to invoke the method.

You can define the function seperately as either a function declaration

```
function someFunction() {
    // code
}
```

or a function variable

```
var someFunction = function () {
    // code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call it:

```
function_holder.someFunction()
```

From outside:

```
function other() {
    alert('Outside');
}

var obj = {
    someFunction: other
};

obj.someFunction(); // alerts Outside;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write this instead:

`function_holder.someFunction = function() { }`

You can call the function this way:

`function_holder.someFunction()`

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple different ways to do what you want to do.

```
function function_holder() {

    this.my_function = function() {};
};
```

You would call this by instantiating function holder as such.

```
var fc = new function_holder();
fc.my_function();
```

Or alternatively you could do it this way.

```
function function_holder() {};

function_holder.prototype.my_function = function() {};
```

You would call this the following way:

```
function_holder.my_function();
```

Comment: That's wrong. `function_holder` is an object and `new <Object>` throws a type error

Answer (score 0):

call it:
`function_holder.someFunction()` 
This will execute the function like the others say.

I think I have an idea what you mean by "write someFunction outside of function_holder?"..

```
var theFunc = function(){};
function_holder = {};
function_holder.someFunction = theFunc;
```

There are lots of ways to do anything in javascript.